# How to import variable from Shell script in Python?

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a Shell script, lets call it `file.sh`, that identifies a variable `LOGFILE`. I am trying to run a Python script calling the same variable, however it is not exporting properly.

I tried:

```py
import os
print(os.environ(LOGFILE))
```

and got this error: `name 'LOGFILE' is not defined`

They are in the same directory, so I am not sure what the error is? How can I fix this?

Comment: According to the Python syntax, `LOGFILE` is the name of a variable, and you would have to define the variable before using it. Have a look at [this](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/python-variables) tutorial. Actually, you can't do any serious Python programming without understanding the concept of a _variable_.

Comment: _that identifies a variable LOGFILE_ : If you only define a variable in your bash script, it won't be visible in child processes of your script. You would have to define it especially as **environment** variable.

Answer (score 3):

The environment variable is not directly accessible as python variable.  This is why you need to pass the name of the external environment-variable in the form of a string.  Furthermore, environ is not a function, it is a dictionary, so you need to use square brackets to lookup 'LOGFILE' in the dictionary:

```
print(os.environ['LOGFILE'])
```

If you want a function that does something similar, use os.getenv()

```
print(os.getenv('LOGFILE'))
```

Comment: I just tried that and getting the same error.

Comment: Exactly the same error?  I would now guess that you would at least get a KeyError from my first example, and a result of None from my second example.   In the shell script, are you exporting the shell script variable? LOGFILE="xyz"; export LOGFILE

Comment: @marina : I don't believe that you get the **same** error. Show a screenshot of your Python program to prove it.